# How can I pause and wait for user input with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, casperjs, puppeteer, headless-browser

I need to make `Puppeteer` pause and wait for user input of `username` and `password` before continuing. It is a `nodejs` 8.12.0 app.

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();   
    await page.goto('https://www.myweb.com/login/');

    //code to wait for user to enter username and password, and click `login`

    const first_page = await page.content();

   //do something 

    await browser.close();
)}();
```

Basically the program is halted and waits until the user clicks the `login` button. Is it possible to do this in `Puppeteer`? Or what else can I do?

Comment: you will be the one to trigger that action right? so why do you want to wait indefinitely for an action to happen?

Comment: Hi, the user will enter login information and the code not continue without a valid login.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`page.waitForFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) to wait for a function to return a truthy value before continuing.

The following function will wait until the `#username` and `#password` fields contain a value before continuing:

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => {
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  
  return username.length !== 0 && password.length !== 0;
});
```

But since you are entering the `#username` and `#password` yourself, you can simply use:

```
await page.type('#username', 'username');
await page.type('#password', 'password');
await page.click('#login');
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

Comment: This ist not possible with headless: true I guess? I'm running puppeteer in a lambda function so it is always headless. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  How could you wait for user input when a user can't view a headless browser?  @Tobi

Comment: He probably wants to ask a remote user for an input and them pass it to puppetteer

Comment: Then he can just await any promise outside of puppeteer

Comment: I want to know what would happen when we deploy this thing to cloud servers, we don't have GUI there, how would we able to replicate these steps ?

Comment: @MuhammadUzair You would pair the waitForFunction promise with another promise that fetches what you need with Promise.all. This answer is not meant for the cloud but can be easily modified for such a scenario.